# Can view parts of deleted posts in SE search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, search, deleted-questions

If I make a search on stackexchange.com, I can view parts of deleted posts:

For example, [this search](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Anti+aging+wrinkle+cream) gives me some text from a deleted post:

> ... Nuplenish To find a great anti- cream that'll actually perform, ... An exceptional wrinkle product is going to not be difficult on your own skin ... But skin care marketing is not empty of jokes and methods to sell anti-aging products.

Comment: Stack Exchange can't  do anything about it, since it's cached by Google.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You missed something, so here it is with a FHRC:

> [image]

Or in words: those are Google Search results, meaning it was cached by Google. Stack Exchange doesn't  really have control over Google Cache.

Besides, if someone is *looking* for spam, he/she will find spam, so it's not a big deal. :)

Comment: Searched for SPAM, did not find a single bit of processed pork shoulder.

Comment: @Mark obviously, spammers never use the word SPAM themselves. ;-)

Comment: @Mark search for muscle or probiotic or something!